# How to set drawables vector asset as my activity background?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I am trying to set vector asset as background but I am getting errors
logcat

logcat image [logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4gDY.png)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable in.technicalkeeda.login_design:drawable/ic_testback with resource ID #0x7f060057
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_testback.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060057
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:854)

main activity

```
package in.technicalkeeda.login_design;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[layout.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myOJF.png)

Answer (score 0):

use-->

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_testback"
```

instead of `srcCompat`

Answer (score 0):

After set the content view of the activity, set background of the root view of your activity through below code.

```
View root = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_testback);
```